# Trying to place an image in a fixed positon. Why the image is misplaced until I do a page refresh?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, image, codesandbox

Newbie here.

I just started playing around with ReactJS on codesandbox.
I want to keep an image element (the green arrow) in a specific position over the gauge element. I tried it the simplest way I could think of, and it kinda suits what I need, but...
When I open the page, the image is misplaced, but if I do a page refresh, the image will be exactly where I want it... why?! What can be the reason and any idea of how to solve it?
Perhaps, can you tell me any other way of positioning an image in a specific place inside the div?

Here's the link: https://codesandbox.io/embed/gauge-ship-engine-1-h2nhx?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark&codemirror=1

Here's the code:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import "./styles.css";
import ReactSpeedometer from "react-d3-speedometer";
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
import Container from "react-bootstrap/Container";
import Row from "react-bootstrap/Row";
import Col from "react-bootstrap/Col";
import arrow from "./greenarrow.png";

class Gauge extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      value: ""
    };

    this.handleGaugeValueChange = this.handleGaugeValueChange.bind(this);
  }

  handleGaugeValueChange(e) {
    console.log(1);

    this.setState({
      value: e.target.value
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="center">
        <h1 className="title">Ship Engine 1</h1>

        <Container className="p-3">
          <Row>
            <Col>
              <div
                className="speedometer"
                style={{
                  width: "100%",
                  display: "flex",
                  justifyContent: "center",
                  alignItems: "center"
                }}
              >
                <img
                  src={arrow}
                  alt="greenarrow"
                  style={{
                    position: "absolute",
                    opacity: 1,
                    zIndex: "1",
                    transform: "rotate(-35deg)",
                    marginLeft: "-65px",
                    marginTop: "-80px"
                  }}
                />

                <ReactSpeedometer
                  maxValue={150}
                  ringWidth={20}
                  customSegmentStops={[0, 30, 55, 65, 90, 120, 150]}
                  segmentColors={[
                    "#FAFAFA",
                    "#FAFAFA",
                    "#007fff",
                    "#FAFAFA",
                    "#FAFAFA",
                    "#FAFAFA"
                  ]}
                  needleHeightRatio={0.72}
                  valueTextFontSize="19px"
                  needleTransitionDuration={9000}
                  needleTransition="easeElastic"
                  currentValueText="${value} kW"
                  value={this.state.value}
                />
              </div>
              <div className="divLabelReq">
                <label
                  className="labelReq"
                  htmlFor="value"
                  style={{ color: "#6b6964" }}
                >
                  Requested: 39.7kW
                </label>
              </div>
            </Col>
            <Col>
              <form className="form-settings" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                <div className="form-row">
                  <div className="form-group col-md-5">
                    <label
                      className="label"
                      htmlFor="value"
                      style={{ color: "white" }}
                    >
                      Change Gauge Value:{" "}
                    </label>
                    <input
                      type="number"
                      className="form-control"
                      name="value"
                      id="value"
                      placeholder="0"
                      onChange={this.handleGaugeValueChange}
                      value={this.state.keywords}
                    />
                  </div>
                </div>
              </form>
            </Col>
          </Row>
        </Container>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Gauge;

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<Gauge />, rootElement);
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This might be a lib related bug because you can fix the issue by just toggling the margin CSS prop. And that shouldn't happen. Did you try to isolate the problem?

Comment: Thanks for the answer! How do I toggle a property in react? No, didn't tried it yet

Comment: If you open dev tools on chrome for example, under the elements tab, on the right side you have website CSS props. You can play around with them there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your green arrow has not a reference. For instance the parent element has not a position declared. Try something like:

```
         <div
            className="speedometer"
            style={{
              width: "100%",
              display: "flex",
              justifyContent: "center",
              alignItems: "center",
              position: "relative"
            }}
          >
```

Comment: Ahh!! Eu sabia que faltava alguma coisa! Entao era isso! Muito obrigado :)